# MySQL Database Dump Restores to Smaller Size

Tags: database, mysql

I just started using [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) to manage my databases at work. I was previously using NaviCat, and I was able to simply drag and drop a database from one server to a database on another server and copy all the tables and data--piece of cake, backed up. Similar functionality isn't obvious in Heidi, but I decided using mysqldump is a standard way of backing up a database and I should get to know it.

I used Heidi to perform the dump--creating databases, creating tables, inserting data, and making one single SQL file. This was performed on one single database that is 801.7 MB (checksum: 1755734665). When I executed the dump file on my local doppelganger database it appeared to work flawlessly, however the database size is 794.0 MB (checksum: 2937674450).

So, by creating a new database from a mysqldump of a database I lost 7.7 MB of something (and the databases have different checksums--not sure what that means though). I searched and found a post saying that performing a mysqldump can optimize a database, but could not find any conclusive information.

Am I being a helicopter parent? Is there any easy way to make sure I didn't lose data/structure somehow?

Thank you,
Kai

Comment: You might want to verify that your data is not corrupted just in case. Here is a link that explains identifying table corruption: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/how-do-you-identify-innodb-table-corruption

Comment: I don't how you get the size but if it is os file size than it can be misleading. File size is getting bigger as you need but not the opposite if you don't optimize tables therefore your file size will be the peak value even if you delete all records from database. On the other hand when you dump database it dumps the data in it with necessary object creation scripts. And when you load it creates necessary files from scratch and inserts the data. So AFAIK there can be difference in size.

Comment: Nothing lost.  Just defragmentation, sort of.  More details here:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/280080/1876